# How to "add half of the minimum positive value (among all) to all the response value" before taking log

Tags: sas, transformation

Some of my response variable's values are zero. I want to find whatever the positive minimum value is, divide it by 2 and add that amount to all of the original values before taking log. Please help me do this. This is my current code but it doesn't seem right.

```
data dat; set dat;
    lvar = log(var + (min(var) / 2));
run;
```

And here is some sample data

```
data dat;
cards;
a var
1 0
2 5
3 6
4 7
5 10
6 2
7 0
8 4
9 0
;
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Can you use SQL instead of a data step? The code will work in SQL but not a data step, because the MIN function operates differently between the two. The way you're using it now, is how it works in PROC SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a DATA step, you could do this with a double-DoW loop.  Instead of relying on the implicit DATA step loop, you make the looping explicit.  In one DATA step, you read through the data once to find the minimum, then read it a second time to compute lvar and output records.

Something like:

```
data want;

  *loop through all records, to find the minimum;
  do until(eof);
    set dat end=eof;

    if var ne 0 then minvar=min(var,minvar);
  end;
  eof=0; *reset eof flag;


  *loop through the records again, computing lvar;
  *and outputting each record;
  do until(eof);
    set dat end=eof;
    lvar=log(var+minvar);
    put (_all_)(=);
    output;
  end;
run;
```